# Confused about using ion auth or building custom authentication library

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

Hi I am building my first website with codeigniter. I am using registration form to allow users to register on the site. I have already built up the form and was heading towards login methods when I came across some authentication libraries in codeigniter. Some of them were ion auth, tank auth, etc. I heard that ion auth is pretty good one over others I want to know whether it is worth using it now when I have built my registration system already or should I skip to building custom authentication library?

Answer (score 2):

All of these authentication libraries work in 90% of users needs. For instance Tank auth (my personal favorite) has a lot of features which can be disabled (so it is modular) and thus you can create authentication with elements suitable for your web site. If you find these elements necessary and you do not have time/knowledge/... to code it yourself, I suggest that you implement library. 
However if you have some special authentication requirements or you do not need those additional features, you should stick with your custom made. Or you can choose to write one yourself, and use it in your projects. Benefits of custom made auth library are: you will learn a lot in the way and you will have all the features you want and need just the way you like it.
Both ways have good/bad sides - it is up to you.
Thank you for your time. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

If all you've built out so far is the views you can easily drop Ion Auth in to handle your authentication.

The controller and views included with Ion Auth are just examples to get people started.